# HTML table alignment not working correctly

Tags: html, css, layout, html-email

I am currently creating a HTML email template. I have a table with 3 columns for the following:

[[logo]  [text content                       ]  [date]]

So the logo should be left aligned, and the date right aligned. However in outlook it doesn't look like the float is being accepted. [this is how it currently looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdxB9.png).

Here is my current code:

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap; margin-bottom:10px; width:100%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="6%"> <img style="float:left; margin-right:10px;" height="24px" width="30px" src="{{imageUrl}}">
      </td>
      <td width="63%;">
        {{this.notificationMessage}}
      </td>
      <td width="30%" style="text-align:right; margin-left:6px;">{{this.date}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have been stuck with this issue for sometime, any help is much appreiacted

Comment: Hey did you try to add float:right to the date <td>

Comment: @DevKosov Yup that also made no difference so i took it out

Comment: try to add float:right for date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **Float: right** and i think you should omit anything about flex ( i mean: display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap;).

```
<html>
<body>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style=" margin-bottom:10px; width:100%;">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td width="6%"> <img style="float:left; margin-right:10px;" height="24px" width="30px" src="img.."> 
         </td>
         <td width="63%;">
           aa
         </td>
         <td width="30%" style="text-align:right;float:right; margin-left:6px;">bb
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While there are other valid answers, this was the first one that was posted that worked, I shall mark this as correct answer. Thanks all

Comment: Have you tested this in the big email clients? Float may work in the email client you're using, but not others.

Comment: It's best to test all. Safest is `align`

Answer (score 3):

HTML should be coded as if it's the year 1999.

Tables should be used for layout and the use of modern HTML and CSS is best avoided where possible.

In your case above you should just use the align attribute on the table cell e.g.

```
<td align=left"></td>

<td align=right"></td>
```

If that doesn't work then try using CSS e.g.

```
<td style="text-align: left;"></td>
```

Here's a good guide to creating HTML email template from Mailchimp:

https://templates.mailchimp.com/getting-started/html-email-basics/

Answer (score 0):

You can give "text-align: left" for  of  also instead of "float: left" on

Comment: That didn't seem to work either here is how it looks with your suggestion:

https://imgur.com/a/f1tD65O

Answer (score 0):

You have to `style="text-align:left; "` for td.

Use below corrected code.

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap; margin-bottom:10px; width:100%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="6%" style="text-align:left;" > <img style="float:left; margin-right:10px;" height="24px" width="30px" src="{{imageUrl}}">
      </td>
      <td width="63%;" style="text-align:left;" >
        Notification message
      </td>
      <td width="30%" style="text-align:right; margin-left:6px;">date
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```